# Does the current increase in a wire if a surplus amount of electrons is added to the wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrons, electromagnetic-induction

Assume that an LED is placed in a closed-loop of wire (ring) being located on the table. A bar magnet located a specific distance away from the table/ring is released to fall under the influence of gravity toward the center of the ring. We know that the LED would glow due to the induction of an electric field in the ring. Now, if we repeat the same experiment replacing the wire with one that has been charged with a surplus amount of electrons, does the LED glow brighter?

If so, what if we add an extremely high amount of electrons to the wire? Does it mean that there is no upper limit for the brightness of LED in this way since we can charge the wire with surplus electrons unlimitedly based on classical electromagnetism?

Comment: In my view, the surplus amount of electrons simply reduces the resistance of the wires (the more charge available to move, the lesser the resistance). So the LED will glow only a tiny bit brighter, given the lower resistance to the induced EMF. But to all purposes, the answer is sooner no because the change is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the surplus amount of electrons simply reduces the resistance of the wires (the more charge available to move, the lesser the resistance). So the LED will glow only a tiny bit brighter, given the lower resistance to the induced EMF. But to all purposes, the answer is sooner no because the change is minimal.

The conductivity \ resistivity depend on free charge availability, and that's the only thing you'd be changing in effect. It's like switching the ring to a more conductive material.

Even if the resistance of the wire dropped to an ideal zero, the brightness of the LED will be: EMF = (resistance LED) * (current). The LED has a different resistance for every current level of course, but for the given EMF there will be a particular resistance and current. Otherwise, if the loop retains some resistance, EMF = R(loop) * I0 + R(led at current I0) * I0

If your loop is made of a semiconductor, the additional electrons might make all the difference and reduce loop resistance substantially. But if it's already a Cooper wire, reducing the resistance from 1 Ohm to 0.1 Ohm hardly makes a difference. The LED resistance is much more significant.

Comment: What if we add an extremely high amount of electrons? According to your answer, does it mean that there is no upper limit for the brightness of LED in this way?

Comment: I believe that even if the resistance of the wire dropped to an ideal zero, the brightness of the LED will be: EMF = (resistance LED) * (current). The LED has a different resistance for every current level of course, but for the given EMF there will be a particular resistance and current. Otherwise, if the loop retains some resistance, EMF = Rloop * I + Rled * I

Comment: At some point, by the way, increasing the number of electrons might backfire because they'll "collide" more. The conductivity depends on the number of free electrons, but also on a mobility factor. But in any case, there is plenty resistance from the LED itself, so a zero resistance wire, doesn't lead to zero resistance in the loop because the LED is there. If there remains wire resistance it's just a matter of a "voltage divider" between the two elements, even as here the voltage is undefined, so I guess EMF divider.